# using resolve in a ui router parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i was trying to  use Angular JS to consume web api of a simple patient DB , where each patient is having a list of medications.
each of the medication and the patient has its own add , edit and list actions.
when i tried to make the edit of a patient, i have added the option of adding a new medicine(this should also be sort of editing the patient entry).
so i have used the nest state concept of nested states, where the patient edit is the parent state, while the patientedit.Medications is the child state as follows:

```
.state("patientEdit", {
    abstract: true ,
    url: "/patient/edit/:PatID",
    templateUrl: "app/patients/patientEditView.html",
    controller: "PatientEditCtrl as vm",
    resolve: {
        patientResource: "patientResource",

        patient: function (patientResource, $stateParams) {

            console.log("the value of PatID is " + PatID);
            console.log("Patient Edit is called ???")
            return patientResource.get(
                { PatID: PatID }).$promise;

        }
    }
})

.state("patientEdit.Medications", {
    url: "/medications/:MedID/:PatID",
    templateUrl: "app/patients/patientEditMedicationsView.html",
    controller: "medicationEditCtrl as vm",
    resolve: {
        medicationResource: "medicationResource",

        medication: function (medicationResource, $stateParams) {
            var MedID = $stateParams.MedID;
            var PatID = $stateParams.PatID;
            console.log("the value of PatID is " + PatID);
            console.log("the value of MedID is " + MedID);
            console.log("Medication Edit is called ???");
            return medicationResource.getMedication(
                { MedID: MedID, PatID: PatID }).$promise;

        }
    }
})
```

i transition to the create medicine (which is the child state in the code above as follows ) when clicking a button in the patient detail view

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"
    data-ui-sref="patientEdit.Medications({MedID: 0, PatID: vm.patient.ID})"
    style="width:160px">
     Creat New Medicine
</a>
```

i have known from several posts here in stack over flow and the documentation of nested states that child state would wait till resolution of parent state , and also that i can use the resolved parent object from the parent state in the child state and controller.
what happens is that after i click the button for new medicine , and according to the network tab in the development tools both patient in parent state and medication in child state has been resolved correctly (according to the Response tab of the network of dev tools), but there is no transition 
happening anywhere.

**Edit**
here is the Controllers for the aforementioned states that I'm using:
patientEditCtrl.JS:

```
(function () {

angular.module("patientManagement")
   .controller("PatientEditCtrl",
                [ "patient", "$state", PatientEditCtrl]);

function PatientEditCtrl(patient, $state) {
    var vm = this;
   // vm.title = "Editing";
    vm.patient = patient;
    if (patient == null)
    {
        vm.title = "New medication";
    }
    else {
        console.log("here is the Parent controller of editing");
    if (  (vm.patient.ID ) ) {
        console.log("here is the controller of editing");
        vm.title = "Edit: " + vm.patient.Name;
    }
    else {
        console.log(vm.patient.Id);
        vm.title = "New Patient";
    }
    }
    vm.submit = function () {
        vm.patient.$save();
    }
    vm.cancel = function () {
        $state.go('patientList');
    } 

}

}());
```

medicationEditCtrl.Js

```
(function () {

    angular.module("patientManagement")
       .controller("medicationEditCtrl",
                    ["medication", "$state", medicationEditCtrl]);

    function medicationEditCtrl(medication, $state) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.medication = medication;
        console.log("we are in medication edit CTRL");
        if ((vm.medication.MedID)) {
            console.log("here is the controller of editing a medication ");
            vm.title = "Edit: " + vm.medication.Name;
        }
        else {
            console.log(vm.medication.MedID);
            console.log("having a patientId of " + vm.medication.PatID);
            vm.title = "New Medication";
        }
        vm.submit = function () {
            vm.medication.$save();
        }
        vm.cancel = function () {
            $state.go('patientList');
        }



    }

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the service that i was using :

```
(function () {

"use strict";
angular.module("common.services")
       .factory("patientResource", ["$resource", patientResource]);

function patientResource($resource) {
    console.log("service is called");
    return $resource("http://localhost:49190/api/patients/:Id");

};

}());
```

while i was calling it using (PatId), so the required solution was to change the service call in the resolve of the state named "patientEdit" to be as follows:

```
return patientResource.get({ Id: PatID }).$promise;
```

thanks again for your time and replies